# Ionic 3 ScreeenOrientation no funciona

Tags: ionic3

Desarrollo una app y **quiero que en una página en particular (se llama *juego* la página) la rotación sea portrait, SIEMPRE**. las otras páginas, libres de rotar.

Seguí la documentación de [screen-orientation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation), pero obtengo solo un mensaje de error como este:

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>           at ScreenOrientation.get [as type] (index.js:45)
>           at JuegoPage.webpackJsonp.447.JuegoPage.ionViewDidLoad (juego.ts:14)
>           at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:486)
>           at ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:369)
>           at NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:768)
>           at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>           at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
>           at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>           at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
>           at NgZone.run (core.js:4577)

En detalle lo que hice:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

en app.module.ts hice:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
```

y en providers dentro de app.module.ts......

```
ScreenOrientation
```

luego en juego.ts (la pagina especifica) hice:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
...
constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation, bla bla
...
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log(this.screenOrientation.type);
  }
```

Mas detalles

global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir el siguiente código dentro de las llaves de tu constructor

```
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
    });
```

Comment: Gracias David, continúa el error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ScreenOrientation.lock (index.js:42)

Comment: Resuelto, era un problema en la instalación del plugin, he seguido la documentación, pero desde https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/screen-orientation/

Muchas gracias